# Newton's Third Law?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, laws-of-physics

I've recently met with this new law and the way my teacher worded is so off for me.

Shouldn't the equal and opposite reaction cancel out the action because they are equal?

Apparently not?

Why?